# Python venv ModuleNotFoundError

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-venv

(Before marking me with duplicate question votes, please note that everything that I can find on this question has to do with virtualenv, not venv)

**System**:

- Ubuntu Server 16.04
- Python 3.6 installed, Python 3.5 native

**Background**
(Contrived example, so might have a typo or two, but the idea is the important part)

I have a project in the form of:

```
Project/
├── __init__.py
└── project
    ├── packageA
    │   ├── fileA.py
    │   └── __init__.py
    └── packageB
        ├── fileB.py
        └── __init__.py
```

in fileb.py, I have an import statement such as

```
import project.packageA.fileA
```

I create a venv by;

```
cd /path/to/Project; python3.6 -m venv .venv; source .venv/bin/activate
```

then I run

```
source project/packageB/fileB.py
```

This will give me an error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'project'
```

**Attempts to address**:

1. Add the path to "Project" and "project" to $PATH
2. Modify $PYTHONPATH in the .venv/bin/activate script so that sys.path now points to "Project" and "project"
3. Completely read the docs [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/venv.html)
4. Verified that os.sys.path shows Project and project paths

**Question**: It must be possible to do module imports using venv or it would be of zero value -- so what am I fundamentally missing in my setup? (With viritualenv, I just used 'add2virtualenv')

[**Edit** - Showing more detail]

```
# Changes to .venv/bin/activate
PYTHONPATH="/home/steve/Temp/Project:/home/steve/Temp/Project/project:$PYTHONPATH"
export PYTHONPATH

python -c "import os; print(os.sys.path)"
['', '/home/steve/Temp/Project', '/home/steve/Temp/Project/project', .....
```

[**Edit2** - adding packageA to PYTHONPATH Works]

If I add 'path/to/packageA' to my PYTHONPATH, the import works. To use this, I would have to add each subpackage to my project -- less than ideal for large projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a somewhat murky situation IMHO. My solution to this is: create a setup.py for your project (beneficial anyways), and with activated venv do a "python setup.py develop".

That will add your project to a PTH-file, and thus you can import.

Example for a setup.py, taken from the interwebs:

```
# from http://python-packaging.readthedocs.io/en/latest/minimal.html

from setuptools import setup

setup(name='funniest',
      version='0.1',
      description='The funniest joke in the world',
      url='http://github.com/storborg/funniest',
      author='Flying Circus',
      author_email='flyingcircus@example.com',
      license='MIT',
      packages=['funniest'],
      zip_safe=False)
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Do you happen to know which "PTH" file it is added? Couldn't I add to that same file independently of setup?

Comment: Well, this seemed to work -- but it is total bull ship - I can't believe a tool would be shipped without an elegant way to deal with something as fundamental as imports -- Anyway, your just the messenger so thanks for getting me out of a bind.

Comment: I have to admit this was always a bit of a nuisance for me as well. OTOH most things I do end up having a setup.py eventually, so.... Apparently virtualenv has something (didn't even know it) called add2virtualenv. Ultimately it's probably 20 lines of code making that happen for venv - you might consider filing a bug.

Comment: As for the pth file - no idea. Just grep through the site-packages and look for your packages path.

Answer (score 4):

This line

```
​$ source project/packageB/fileB.py
```

fails because

1. the `import` path is messed up, it includes the `project` folder but it should not
2. `project` is *possibly* not in your `PYTHONPATH`

To fix it

Step 1) fix the `import` statement in `fileB.py`, replace your `import` with

```
​import packageA.fileA
```

Step 2) Confirm for yourself whether you added `project` to `PYTHONPATH` by checking your `bash` environment

```
​$ echo $PYTHONPATH     # does it contain `path/to/project`?
```

If not temporarily fix it

```
​$ export PYTHONPATH=path/to/project:$PYTHONPATH   # forget `/path/to/Project` you only need `path/to/Project/project`
```

(Note changes to `$PATH`  are irrelevant to `Python package/module` searches, so that was a wasted attempt).

Then when you run your script, it will not fail:

```
$ source project/packageB/fileB.py      # success?!
```

By the way it is better to call your python scripts with `python`:

```
$ python project/packageB/fileB.py
```

Finally, permanently update your virtual environment by editing the `activate` script in your virtual environment's `bin` directory. Add the `PYTHONPATH` export above somewhere near the top.

Comment: My example was simplified,  indeed each package has an init file as does 'project'. My PYTHON path was added in the venv/bin/activate file. I confirm this by python -c "import os; print (os.sys.path)". I added Project and project. Additionally, the imports work as is when run from within pycharm. I'll update the details in the morning, but I think I already have the bases covered. Unless you are saying that for nested packages I have to add all the sub directories to the last branch. I do really appreciate yor help, BTW ... this is kicking my tail.

Comment: Also, deets approach makes it work with the imports as they are. Additionally using legacy virtual envs with add2virtualenv makes the imports work.

Comment: Okay, I’ve edited out the reference to `__init__.py` in my Answer since I see you have edited it into your Question.